# When i press Stop and then Play the sound dont works

Tags: android, playsound

i have a simple app with 2 buttons. When i press Play, the sound run correctly, but when i press Pause and then play, the sound don´t works.
Why?

Here my code:
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);

 Button Play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp.start();
    }});


    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

         mp.stop();
         //mp.reset();

        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: you need to post your logcat

Comment: Here when you press the pause button Actually you are stoping the player so you need to realease and start again then only your player will run.

Comment: @AmarRaj How? :C
If i close the app and open it again, works good

Comment: @AndroidGeek https://github.com/Hersix/Logcat-SweetDreams/blob/master/LogcatSweetDreams
Thanks

Comment: can you add "final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);" in button pause after mp.stop();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use stop() for pausing media. Use pause() and check isPlaying() or not before pausing() it.

Answer (score 0):

change to this:

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mp != null) {
         mp.stop();
         mp.release();
    }
    }
});
```